# Reputation for retagging

Tags: support, tagging, reputation

I'm not a 100% sure but I think I remember that sometimes retagging a question gave me 2 points of reputation and sometimes I didn't earn any reputation from retagging.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour or do I just remember wrong? And in case this is true, what is the explanation for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you get the ["retag questions" privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) (500 rep), you no longer need to edit a question (thereby gaining 2 points) to retag a question – simply retagging gains you no points. If you have the ["edit questions and answers" privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) (2000 rep), you get no points for editing questions.

Answer (score 11):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

When you reach 500 rep, you gain the privilege to retag questions. With less than 500 rep, you would get 2 points if a suggested retag was approved.